# Get all comments on URL share

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Im interested to know if there is a way using API to get list of consolidated comments for an URL shared in facebook.

What I have tried is using following API to get object_ID of an URL "http://graph.facebook.com/?id={URL}"
and then used "{object_ID}/comments". As a result, I got following output and not able to figure out what I have missed.

{   "data": [   ] }

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You mean the comments that are made on the Facebook posts that have shared this URL? No, that is not possible - those comments “belong” to the Facebook post, they are not tied to your URL in any way.

Comment: CBroe, Thanks for your reply.I can get count of comments posted on all shares for the URL. If these are not tied to the URL does it mean these counts are estimated from the API. Is there a way from Facebook search functionality to see all these shares.

Comment: No, there is no way to see all shares. Posts on user profiles for example would only become visible to your app, if the user that made the post logged in to it and granted it permissions.